# hudson build timedout | how to perform cleanup in such case?

Tags: hudson

Suppose a particular job is executing for more then x minutes then I abort it using the [build timout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin.)
Now after the build is aborted in such manner I want to  perform some cleanup actions.  Want to know - how can I do it?
How can I kill all process that my build had started?

To perform such action I found a post build plugin.http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task

But I get follwing error when it tries to execute my bat script

```
Build timed out. Aborting
Build was aborted
Performing Post build task...
Match found for :aborted : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : C:\aks.bat
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\hudson6930497910994453428.bat
Exception when executing the batch command : null
Finished: ABORTED
```

Why is it so?  Can anyone suggest some other plugin?

Comment: That looks to me as if the post build step is executing the aks.bat script, but there is an error in the script itself.  Can you put some debugging output in the script and post back the results ?

Comment: there is no problem in batch script as i have executed it normally /direclty and it works fine

Comment: If you execute a batch script normal/directly you might get a totally different behavior than when you run it from Hudson that runs it in a new shell with perhaps different environmental variables...

Comment: Was anyone able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please paste the content of your aks.bat, cause as others have said, the error seems to be inside that batch.